# EXCEL multiple condition based on the date

Tags: excel

```
s.DATE       E.DATE      NAME        E VALUE     DAILY  s.year       Fin. 
20-Oct-17   19-Oct-19   SHABEER 2    3,210.00    4.41   1-Sep-17    31-Aug-18
26-Sep-17   25-Sep-19   ALIKOYA 2    3,220.00    4.42   1-Sep-17    31-Aug-18

=IF(AND(B2<H2),E2-(B2-G2)*F2,"")&IF(AND(A2>G2),E2-(H2-A2)*F2,"")&IF(AND(A2<G2),E2-(H2-G2)*F2,"")&IF(AND(A2=G2),E2-(H2-A2)*F2,"")
```

I am using this formula to find out value based on the date .i want if the first condition true`(IF(AND(B2<H2),E2-(B2-G2)*F2,"")` stop going through next conditions

thank you

Comment: Your `AND` functions here are redundant as you only have one condition for each, e.g. `AND(B2<H2)` can just be `B2<H2`

Answer (score 0):

nest the IFs and as @BarryHoudini stated the AND is redundant:

```
=IF(B2<H2,E2-(B2-G2)*F2,IF(A2>G2,E2-(H2-A2)*F2,IF(A2<G2,E2-(H2-G2)*F2,IF(A2=G2,E2-(H2-A2)*F2,""))))
```